# What does "dark - flowering" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am confused about the meaning of "dark - flowering kisses". Would be so grateful for any ideas, as I have none :(

Here's the context:
"Before he knew what he was doing,he crushed his mouth over hers, holding her head so
she couldn’t jerk back. She tasted like lavender sugar. Sweet, **dark-flowering** kisses, opening in a way that focused all his senses on this one moment, this one blinding perception of pleasure."

Excerpt from Lisa Kleypas book "Dream Lake"

Comment: Isn't she just continuing the theme of a lavender from taste to analogy? The next word is "opening", as in the marvel of a flower opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a metaphor describing the kisses as like flowers that bloom at night.  It is certainly more poetical than precise.